# Python app detected as virus by defender after addition of classes

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

Not too long ago I changed a lot of my code around in my project to use classes. I'm fairly certain that ever since I did switch to classes. The program is now identified as a virus by windows defender. Prior it was not. I have an old build from last month that is not destroyed by windows defender.

Is there any way I can identify what exactly in my code is causing windows defender to detect it as a virus? I'm using `auto-py-to-exe` to build the program. I unfortunately do not have much of a record of previous versions of the application. Aside from an old build.

This is a [VirusTotal report of the current build](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6dd9c219d51290990635c59641266ec196152b47b0bafd0c081be9b8cb4350c4/detection). [This is the old build](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/7e732d8d2f5958acc2595a1fc60070aaa8e18e6a91d57d05161e54550cc297d0?nocache=1). The difference is specifically:
[image]

Comment: Maybe your machine has a virus. Can you rebuild that older build and see if you get different results? If you do frequent checkins, you could go back and find which change was the problem. An automatic build / test setup (continuous delivery) can catch this sort of problem early.

Comment: Do you specify `--uac-admin` to force it to run as administrator?  That adds a file called `wacapew.c` to the exe, which apparently triggers this.  https://www.reddit.com/r/computerviruses/comments/mkrmg7/windows_defender_found_wacapewc_ml/

Comment: @TimRoberts I run auto-py-to-exe as admin else defender will nuke the application mid build. However I've always done that since I've been building it. I just built an older version of the code I had and I still have the `Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml` detected from Microsoft...

Comment: Building old versions of the program. Its something with my gui code that uses custom tkinter. Switching back to a version that didn't use classes. I do NOT get the `Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml ` warning when I test it on virustotal.

Comment: Yes. Something with custom tkinter being in classes causes the program to be detected as `Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml`

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that in my prior code versions. I was importing sys and os from customtkinter. The library packed with custom tkinter doesn't trigger windows defender from what [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/79f7b277931ed676d4f8698aa0dff6c1b4230aadd77ecb47f6d12f1b81fb94f5?nocache=1) says.

In my later version. I was solely importing sys and os by themselves. Changing back to importing from customtkinter solves the issue.

I'm not 100% yet but I'm fairly certain that using `sys` from pip is causing the issue. Using `sys` and `os` included from `customtkinter` and the application is not deleted by windows defender.

It seems it is specific to the `os` library. Specifically using the following and it does not show up as a false positive in defender.

```
import sys
import customtkinter as ctk
from customtkinter import os
```

Comment: *"I'm not 100% yet but I'm fairly certain that using sys from pip is causing the issue. Using sys and os included from customtkinter and the application is not deleted by windows defender."*  - It is the same `sys` and `os` module.  Look at the `customkinter/__init__.py` file.